# Windows batch add suffixes to filenames with EXIF values in current folder with FOR loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-rename, exiftool

I'm trying to get some EXIF data added to the filenames in a folder.  So far, I've been able to get the smaller pieces to work, but I can't get the name and extension separated so the can be combined with the EXIF values via the FOR loop.

I saw that I need to use `!` to delineate the variable in the loop, but I can't get this to work with the filename.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *') do (
    set file=%%~a
    set _fname=%~n1
    set _ext=%~x1
    for /f %%i in ('exiftool.exe -s -S -SourceImageWidth %file%') do set WIDTH=%%i
    for /f %%i in ('exiftool.exe -s -S -SourceImageHeight %file%') do set HEIGHT=%%i
    for /f %%i in ('exiftool.exe -s -S -CompressorID %file%') do set CODEC=%%i
    rename %file% "%_fname% [%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT% %CODEC%]%_ext%"
)
```

The process is: get filename -> get name only -> get extension -> get EXIF values -> rename file with values added to name and reuse extension -> repeat on next file in current directory

I apologize for the sloppy batch syntax as I'm sure there's a much more optimal way of coding.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).  Exiftool's biggest performance hit is its startup time and using it in a loop like this will take a significantly longer time, especially since exiftool has very powerful batch and renaming abilities on its own.

Try this as a single command
`exiftool "-Filename<%f [${SourceImageWidth}x$SourceImageHeight $CompressorID].%e" /path/to/files`

Add [`-r`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.  Remember to [double any percent signs](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q27) if used in a .BAT file.

The `%f` token stands for the base filename without the extention. The tags names are inserted by adding a dollar sign in front of them.  Because `SourceImageWidth` is directly adjacent to the `x`, braces are used to separate the two so exiftool doesn't go looking for a tag named "SourceImageWidthx".  The `%e` stands for the file extension.

Comment: That is fantastic: Thank you for that.  I guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees and I was fixating on using the For Loop instead of just trying to use exiftool by itself.  Thank you again!!